# whitenoise not adding random string

Tags: django, heroku, whitenoise

I just put up another copy of my Django app in production.  The only intended difference between my "old" app and the "new" one is that the old app runs in "traditional" Heroku, and the new app runs in "Dockerized" Heroku.

The weirdest thing is happening.  I use Whitenoise to serve my static assets.  On the older app, links to my static assets look like this in the generated pages:

```
<link href="/static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.9f236e18d5bf.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But on my new app, that little string (9f236e18d5bf) is missing.  it looks like:

```
<link href="/static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As a result, I don't have any stylesheets on my new site.

Is there an additional step that I have to take in the Dockerized version to get this to work?  Or am I missing some combination of STATIC* settings values that are needed.

My temporary workaround was to add `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` to Dockerfile.web, and then set:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

Which works, but I'm wondering if I'm going to get a scaling issue on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the answer comes in two parts, and I had one of each working at different times.

1. Be sure to have this in your Dockerfile.web:

   `RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
   CMD CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 <project-name>.wsgi`

Note that you want to use `RUN` for your `collectstatic` command.  Apparently only the *last* `CMD` value in a Dockerfile makes any sense.

2. In `settings.py`, have

   `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

That setting will cause `collectstatic` to add the hashes to the names of each file that is copied into the directory specified in STATICFILES_ROOT.